# How can I copy node_modules folder out of my docker container onto the build machine?

Tags: node.js, docker, npm

I am moving an application to a new build pipeline. On CI I am not able to install node to complete the NPM install step.

My idea to is to move the npm install step to a Docker image that uses Node, install the node modules and them copy the node modules back to the host so another process can package up the application.

This is my Dockerfile:

```
FROM node:9

# Create app directory
RUN mkdir -p /usr/src/app
WORKDIR /usr/src/app

# Install app dependencies
COPY ./dashboard-interface/package.json /usr/src/app/
RUN npm install --silent --production

# Bundle app src
COPY node_modules ./dashboard-interface/node_modules #I thought this would copy the new node_modules back to the host
```

This runs fine and install the node modules, but when I try and copy the node_modules directory **back to the host** I see an error saying:

```
COPY node_modules ./dashboard-interface/node_modules
COPY failed: stat /var/lib/docker/tmp/docker-builder718557240/node_modules: no such file or directory
```

So it's clear that the copy process cannot find the node_modules directory that it has just installed the node modules too.

Comment: Did you map current folder to the running instance of container ?

`docker run -it --rm -v ${PWD}/:app CONTAINER bash`

Run this and try to create a file i.e `touch test.txt` it should appear in your working directory.

Comment: So I am now trying to mount the volume like so `docker run --rm -v ${PWD}/dashboard-interface:/app docker-container`

Inside the docker file I cant even run `COPY package.json /app` as it cant find package.json which is in the mounted volume.

Comment: which is odd, because doing an `ls /app` at the end of the docker run line shows the contents of the expected local directory

Answer (score 3):

The simple and sure way is to do volume mapping, for example the `docker-compose yaml` file will have a volumes section that looks like this:

```
….
volumes:
    - ./: /usr/src/app
    -  /usr/src/app/node_modules
```

For docker run command, use:

```
-v ./:/usr/src/app
```

and on Dockerfile, define:

```
VOLUME /usr/src/app
VOLUME /usr/src/app/node_modules
```

But confirm first that the run of `npm install` did create the
node_modules directory on the host system.

Answer (score 2):

According to the [documentation of the COPY instruction](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#copy), the COPY instruction copies a file from the host to the container.

If you want the files from the container to be available outside your container, you can use [Volumes](https://docs.docker.com/engine/admin/volumes/volumes/). Volumes will help you have a storage for your container that is independent of the container itself, and thus you can use it for other containers in the future.

Answer (score 2):

Let me try to solve the issue you are having.

Here is the `Dockerfile`

```
# Use alpine for slimer image
FROM node:9-alpine

RUN mkdir /app
WORKDIR /app

COPY /dashboard-folder/package.json . 

RUN npm i --production

COPY node_modules ./root
```

Assumes the following that your project stucture is like so:

```
|root
     |   Dockerfile
     |
     \---dashboard-folder
             package.json
```

Where root is your working directory that will recieve `node_modules`

Building image this image with `docker build . -t name` and subsequently using it like so :

```
docker run -it --rm ${PWD}:/app/root NAME mv node_modules ./root
```

Should do the trick.

Comment: Thanks for the example ukaric, this is working to an extent but fails to the the `node_modules` directory back to the host.

I see this error `Step 6/6 : COPY node_modules ./performance_tests
COPY failed: stat /var/lib/docker/tmp/docker-builder229108403/node_modules: no such file or directory`

`./performance_tests` is the root directory that the dockerfile lives in.

Comment: Yeah I know that is the nature of that `Dockerfile` , you could try and put everything in same folder and then use `RUN` command to do operations on files but that is not ideal.

Comment: I just don't understand why it cant find the `node_modules` dir, If I do an LS of the dir before the copy command I can see the `node_modules` dir there/

Answer (score -1):

The main reason that you hitting the problem is depending on the OS that is running on your host. If your host is running Linux then for sure will be no problem but if your host is on Mac or Windows, then what happened is that docker is actually running on a VM which is hidden from you and hence the path you cannot map directly to host system. Instead, you can use Volume.